# Fetch images from Instagram in iOS

Tags: ios, instagram

I wish to fetch images from Instagram into iOS app. For this I am using Instagram API. I have set clientID and redirect-uri as shown in http://kmdarshan.wordpress.com/2013/02/23/integrating-instagram-sdk-in-your-ios-apps/ and http://instagram.com/developer/

Code used is given in link above. But in the line:

```
if ([[UrlParts objectAtIndex:(1)] isEqualToString:@"NeverGonnaFindMe"]) {...
```

the string always equals to `oauth`. 
Where am I getting wrong? Anyone having any other option to integrate instagram images into iOS apps, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a project to fetch instagram images into ios app on:

https://github.com/hsandhu/HSInstagram

Awesome application, saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this framework to show the instagram feed, both user and tags

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sbinstagram-viewer

is more complete and is easy to integrate

regards